# Struts2 Upgraded to 2.5.28.3 from 2.2.26 and get Freemarker error

Tags: struts2, freemarker

With all the log4j issues, I updated my app from v 2.5.26 to 2.5.28.3 and my app throws this error now.... If i put it back to 2.5.26 its fine... Any ideas???? Seems to be if a field is null it freaks out, but that would seem to be a bug to me??

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-60]
> freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger.error Error executing
> FreeMarker template
> FreeMarker template error:
> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ==> parameters.templateDir  [in template "template/simple/hidden.ftl" at line 38, column 15]

Comment: Check the 2.5.27 rel notes and see if there's anything in there; w/o knowing anything about specifics that'd be the place I'd start. The 2.5.28.n sequence is all Log4J (IIRC) so the changes between 2.5.26 => 2.5.27 would be my starting point.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that encounters this issue...Found a bug listed on their site when you upgrade to 2.5.27+ where if your action has a variable named 'parameters' this bug pops up. Rename it to anything else and the error goes away. At least it did for me.